# Django or Ruby-On-Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, django

I have been looking at jobs. Most of the companies require RoR or Django experience. I don't know any of the languages. The number of organizations working with RoR is greater than Django. But I prefer django because of python.

What do you coders/recruiter suggest me to know?

Comment: One suggestion I would make is that on any communications you send to a potential employer use proper words instead of things like "coz" and "u".  Otherwise it might not matter which of the two you choose.

Comment: thank your Mr Wayne. I will keep a note of it. :)

Comment: Isnt Stackoverflow supposed to be wiki-like? Why hasnt someone (including the OP) just went in and fixed the grammatical errors?

Comment: In that case the comment would not make sense.

Comment: @Wayne Koorts - that's a valuable suggestion.
@kapildalwani - you might also consider reviewing on how to use punctuation and where to capitalize correctly.  The rule of punctuation and usage of capital letters is probably the same for most languages that uses the alphabets.  But regardless, saying English is not one's native language is not an excuse to write improperly.  That's like saying I only learned Java in college, but now my employer is asking me to program in C++, so it's OK for me to  make mistakes.

Comment: Voting to close as this question is about programmers, not about programming.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

My best answer is for you to learn both.

Consider this your end goal, and instead consider your question as, "Which one should I learn first?"

I recommend that you start with Django, especially if you have Python experience. Django's approach, like that of Python itself, is more condusive to learning. Once you've gotten your feet wet, learn Ruby on Rails, because that's the framework that will net you easier cash when you get out into the modern Web 2.0 workforce.

Once you're thoroughly familiar with Ruby on Rails and have been working for a bit, continue learning Django. Refamiliarize yourself with the basics, then start to learn some of the more advanced stuff. Django's inner guts are supposedly easier to dissect than that of Rails. If you ever find yourself faced with a job opening with a surprisingly novel and challenging web platform to implement, you'll find your Django knowledge quite handy.

Here's a bulletized rundown:

### Django

- Great documentation
- Thorough tutorial to ease you in
- Fewer files to understand at first (vs. scaffolding in Rails)
- Built on Python, which you might as well know anyway
- More similar to enterprise stuff like Java Servlets/JSP
- Easier to dig into its innards

### Ruby on Rails

- It's what's hot
- Hot means more jobs
- You want money, don't you?
- When you want to make a "traditional" web 2.0 site, its generated code lets you get done really fast
- Integration with JavaScript libraries
- Built on Ruby, which you might as well know anyway

**Verdict**: Django first (do the tutorial), then Rails, then Django again

Answer (score 19):

I'd suggest you to do some research regarding technologies trends and professionals demand, you can do this by using Google tools, such as [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/?q=django%20python,ruby%20on%20rails,%20asp.net%20mvc&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=1)
[image]

See more details about [technology research here](http://podlipensky.com/2012/06/choosing-web-framework-asp-net-mvc-vs-django-python-vs-ruby-on-rails/). Happy coding!

Comment: Bingo. Django is slowly but surely gaining ground each year, but the Ruby-on-Rails fade is losing a lot of steam.

Comment: Having tried all 3, I can honestly say I am most productive in MVC4. This could be mitigated by good IDE support -- Most of my lost productivity is from default templates/and razor autocompletion in VS

Comment: @Yablargo what's your second choice?

Comment: Roger -- I ended up working alot with Django -- When I am producing self-funded projects, the lower hosting costs make a compelling argument. I feel that the MVC4 is close enough to what you are getting with Rails that I wanted to try something at least a little different. I like Django -- but the IDE and speed of debugging is better in .NET land I believe. I also do alot of projects where the bulk of the software is pure HTML/JS and Rails (from what I read) sort of forces some JS conventions on you. I like to build my JS stuff from the ground up.

Comment: @Cerin slowly gaining ground? The blue bar didn't move from 2006 to 2012, a whole 6 years. You call that gaining ground? Where I live in Northeast, there is not a single django job to be found. You go on job listings, and it's the same three: php, ruby, .net.

Comment: @JohnMerlino, My experience has been the exact opposite. Just searched a job board for Philly, and I found a dozen Django-related job postings in the last week, and I get pinged by recruiters hiring for Django positions in New York about once a week, so I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: @Cerin sure if I had coldfusion listed in my linkedin profile, I would be getting coldfusion recruiters contacting me everyday. Doesn't mean coldfusion is popular.

Comment: @JohnMerlino, Heh, funny you mention that. I actually have both Python/Django and Coldfusion (for historical reasons) mentioned in my Linkedin profile. Guess which one recruiters contact me about.

Comment: This is comparison of lang+framework vs lang+framework, not frameworks vs frameworks

Answer (score 9):

If you're more familiar with Python, then you should do Django. [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) is a big user of Django, and you can use that to "sharpen your saw" in Django skills, for a cost-free investment.

Comment: (Google App Engine was cost-free at the time of this post's writing. Google has since revised the pricing structure and it's no longer so cost-free.)

Comment: I found GAE to be more trouble than it was worth...even with the free price tag. It's No-SQL storage backend makes it incompatible with 90% of Django's builtin apps and other open source addons, so all you get is Django's URL parser and templates. There's a Django No-SQL fork, but it's still a pain to get Django working on GAE, not to mention the maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 8):

Learn both.

Look for a company, where the people (without ties) have fun working there and speak compassionate about there work. This matters far more, than the technology they're working with.

Answer (score 1):

If you are low on time, and have to choose one, just choose the one, for which you know how to program. If you know python, learn django, if you know ruby, learn rails. Both have excellent tutorials, and reference materials, RoR rules in screencasts, django rules documentation and tutorials.
If you have a lot of time on hand, say 3-4 months, then learn both. What's wrong with that?

Comment: What if you don't know either one, and are looking where to begin?

Comment: sorry for late reply.
But, if we don't know both!!!!
I like python personally. 
If u have no background in scripting languages like perl, python ruby. u can start either python or ruby. But if u have prior experience in perl, ruby is the one for you, because ruby is very syntactically similar to perl.

Answer (score 1):

try ruby...I love ruby over python then I prefer rails over django...but if you try ruby and don't like it your best option would be django...

Comment: I love ruby (possibly even over python), but to me django is somehow clearer as to what's going on. Less magic.  So I prefer it over rails.  Both probably work ok these days...the latest hotness these days seems to be the Play framework

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how much convention you are used to. Coming from MVC4 to Django I like alot of things, but find I am writing more code where django calls for configuration vs convention. I have found that there are alot of generic methods that I am finding that reduce this, so it might be a learning curve issue for me.